# How to search date range between 2 DTpicker?

Tags: sql-server, vb6

How to search data using date in vb6 between 2 DTpicker ?
Example October 20, 2019 - October 30 2019 then All the october 20 to october 30 results will be display

```
   loadData "Select CheckDate From tbl_Checklist where 'Format(CheckDate, 'MM dd, yyyy')BETWEEN '" & DTPicker2.Value & "' AND ' " & DTPicker3.Value & " '"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL Query can be like this:

```
Dim sSQLStatement As String
sSQLStatement = "SELECT CheckDate FROM tbl_Checklist WHERE CheckDate BETWEEN #" & DTPickerStart & "# AND #" & DTPickerEnd & "#"
loadData sSQLStatement
```

There are better ways to do this but as a quick fix to get you moving along, it should work. You should use a parameter query and pass it Date typed data.

Comment: there's nothing display in my listview if I select date from 2 dtpicker

Comment: It's working now , I coded it in my dropdown event in dtpicker

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the SQL to search between the dates.. all you need to do is to cast the date picker values to date in the where clause

```
    select 
     your_list_of_columns 
   from your_table
    where some_date_column between cast(DRpicker1value as date) and cast(DRpicker2value as date)
```

Now that you have updated your questions.. you have to do something like this :

```
between Format(DTPicker1.value, "DD-MM-YYYY") & " and " & Format(DTPicker2.value, "DD-MM-YYYY")
```

Comment: Sir may ask if where I will code it,  in my form load or in my dtpicker ?

Comment: see my edited answer above.. format your datepicker values before you pass it to SQL in your where clause (as part of your LoadData statement)

Comment: The code you above sir I will put it on my visual basic 6.0 ,